# Live Event Goal is triggered twice so contact runs through MAT campaign twice

Tags: marketing-automation

Basically what we want to achieve is that a visitor can fill a "contact me" form in and get a "thank you" email on its submission, and add a new contact to a list. What we experience is that in MAT campaign which starts on a goal trigger, the contact runs through twice and receives the "thank you" email twice.

What we noticed: The contact receives the "thank you" twice, once after the form submit and then after the session ends (goal is triggered again).

What we have:

- Contact Form with Submit button + Submit Action
- Submit Action triggers Goal "Contact Form submitted" (IsLiveEvent is checked)
- MAT Campaign which starts when Goal "Contact Form submitted" is triggered and sends a "Thank you email" and adds contact to a specified list, sends inquiry form data to SAP system
- IsLiveEvent is true for the Goal since we want to send the email immediately after the form submit

Is there any way to prevent the live event goal to be triggered when the session ends?
Is there a possibility to extend the start condition for the campaign?
Can we work with delays? Or other elements in the Marketing Automation flow?
Any other thoughts, ideas or experiences?

Comment: You could setup a decision point and set a rule that contact goes through the path if he has **not** triggered the goal before?

Comment: I think this would be a working solution if we want the visitor/customer just to contact once, after that another request in the future would not work out anymore, no email and data to another backendsystem sent etc. We would need also to hide that contact form via personalisation not to confuse the user. I am going to try out e.g 1hour delay as last step for keeping stuck the contact in the MAT flow